# Mongoose models from two connections

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following setup:

**/models/index.js**

```
var glob = require('glob');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/firstDB', {
  useMongoClient: true
});

var models = glob.sync(__dirname + '/*.js', {ignore: '**/index.js'});
models.forEach(function (model) {
  require(model);
});
```

**/models/movie.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('movie', movieSchema);
```

**/app.js**

```
require('./models');
...
var Movie = mongoose.model('movie');
...
```

I would like to access `secondDB` models from the same `app.js` file, how can I do that?

---

**Update:** The end setup should look something like that:
(not sure how to pass the connection to the model)

**/models/index.js**

```
var glob = require('glob');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

var firstConnection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/firstDB', {
  useMongoClient: true
});
var secondConnection = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/secondDB', {
  useMongoClient: true
});

var firstModels = glob.sync(__dirname + '/*.js', {ignore: '**/index.js'});
firstModels.forEach(function (model) {
  require(model);
});
var secondModels = glob.sync(__dirname + '/second/*.js');
secondModels.forEach(function (model) {
  require(model);
});
```

**/models/movie.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('movie', movieSchema);
```

**/models/second/car.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  color: String
}, {timestamps: true});

mongoose.model('car', carSchema);
```

**/app.js**

```
require('./models');
...
var Movie = mongoose.model('movie');
var Car = mongoose.model('car');
...
```

Comment: 1. You want to get data from 2 model files??
2. You just want to access another collection from index.js file??

Comment: I want to get data from 2 models from 2 different mongo connections

Comment: In your question there is 2 `index.js` file where you want to use `secondCollection` ????

Comment: I've updated the question with more details and renamed one of the files to make it less confusing. I would like to access both models (from different collections) on `app.js`

Comment: What is the issue you are facing if you replace `mongoose.connect` with `mongoose.createConnection` in `index.js` file ??

Comment: No issue, my problem is that I don't know how to call it from the model files or the `app.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Thanks!

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var connection1 = mongoose.createConnection('connectionstring1');
var connection2 = mongoose.createConnection('connectionstring2');
```

Check this URL - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

and Go to **Multiple Connection** Section.

**Edit :**

**connectionOne.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),  
    mongoURI = 'mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbOne';

module.exports = connectionOne = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

connectionOne.on('connected', function() {  
  console.log('Mongoose connected to connectionOne');
});

require('./events')
```

**connectionTwo.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),  
    mongoURI = 'mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/dbTwo';

module.exports = connectionTwo = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);

connectionTwo.on('connected', function() {  
  console.log('Mongoose connected to connectionTwo');
});

require('./events')
```

**events.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),  
    connectionOne = require('./connectionOne');

var Event = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  date: { type: Date, required: false }
});

var connectionTwo = require('./connectionTwo');

var newEvent = new mongoose.Schema({  
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  organizer: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = {

    connectionOne.model('Event1', Event); 
    connectionTwo.model('Event2', newEvent);

}
```

For more explanation - [handling-multiple-databases-and-connections-with-mongoose](http://www.zertz.ca/handling-multiple-databases-and-connections-with-mongoose/)

- **Note** - I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the documentation before posting.
I'm not sure how to implement it in my setup.