# How can i connect to multiple mongodb clusters using mongoose.connect in single index.js file in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am have two clusters and I need to get data from both the clusters Db Collection

cluster 1 - mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://usernmae:password@cluster0.1laezrl.mongodb.net/Yearbook10") -> Db - Department -> collection -> Student

cluster 2 -
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://usernmae:password@cluster0.1laezrl.mongodb.net/Yearbook11") -> Db - Department -> collection -> Student

in index.js i need to connect both the cluster at a same time and validate the collection how to do that

Comment: Why don't you work with 2 mongodb connections at the same time? Whats the problem?

Comment: If i give two connection how my model will work which connection it will point? can you give one example of how you are using two connection at same time

Comment: Then I don't understand you. Did you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327392/mongoose-models-from-two-connections ?